# Problem with connecting to some of wireless networks in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless, network-manager, intel-wireless

I've recently instaled ubuntu 12.10 on my lenovo ideapad Y570, and i have a big problem with connecting to some of the wireless networks. So, the one at my home is working just fine, as well as my mobile phone hotspot (both secured with WAP/WAP2 Personal, and WPA (TKIP)), but when I'm going to the library and try to connect with unsecured network there Network Manager, after few seconds of trying, is giving me info that I've gone offline. So I thought that it's security problem, but when I changed mobile hotspot to no-secured I've connected to it without any problem. 
What I've also discovered is that networks which I can't connect "looks" different in connection manager (screen attached).

**lspci -nn**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port [8086:0101] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1c16] (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1c18] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c49] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 555M] [10de:0deb] (rev ff)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b1] (rev 10)
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [8086:0084]
09:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1033:0194] (rev 04)
0a:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller [197b:2392] (rev 30)
0a:00.2 SD Host controller [0805]: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller [197b:2391] (rev 30)
0a:00.3 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller [197b:2393] (rev 30)
0a:00.4 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. xD Host Controller [197b:2394] (rev 30)
```

**lshw -class NETWORK**

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: b8:70:f4:4b:6d:8e
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.123 firmware=sb latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:f1800000-f180ffff memory:f1810000-f181ffff memory:f1820000-f18207ff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 74:e5:0b:51:e0:34
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.5.0-22-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 ip=192.168.1.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:51 memory:f1b00000-f1b01fff
```

Link to screen from network-manager (I can't post pictures) [SCREEN](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkckjn8f63at4mb/Zrzut%20ekranu%20z%202013-01-23%2017:57:39.jpg)

I can not connect to the left one (which have Security as a second card) on the right everything works fine (Security is the last card)

I will gladly provide any additional data that will be required. Also I must ask for a precise, step by step solutions, as I'm a Linux newbie.

Comment: By "looks different," do you mean the icon is different? It might be an adhoc network (as opposed to an infrastructure network).